# Django Cannot find module i'm importing my model from

Tags: python, django, module, models

I'm trying to import a model from another Django app in my project. However, when I try to import, I keep getting an error for:

> ImportError No module named trunk.profiles.models.

However, when I cmnd click on the model on my IDE it takes me to the model. So it recognizes where the model is coming from, but I think for some reason Django is not recognizing the path.

Here is my code from my `models.py` which I'm trying to import another model, Profiles from a different Django app:

```
from django.db import models
from trunk.profiles.models import Profiles # source of error 
class ContentObject(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length15)
    course_topic = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    op_UserName = models.ForeignKey(Profiles)
```

Comment: Is `trunk` on your PYTHONPATH when you run Django?

Answer (score 2):

Add `trunk.profiles` to Your `INSTALLED_APPS`

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'trunk.profiles'
]
```

**TIP**

Instead of import model, specify a model with the full application label

```
from django.db import models
class ContentObject(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length15)
    course_topic = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    op_UserName = models.ForeignKey('trunk.profiles.Profiles')
```